# track bar in media file using DirectShow lib in c#

Tags: c#, directshow

i want to use a track bar in a window form which opens a media file as the video or audio plays i want to move the slider of the track bar accordingly . I had set all the properties of the track bar tool like maximun,minimun, tickfreguency small and large change accordingly.
using mediaposition i collect the currentPosition of the media and total duration using get_duration() method and sets the trackbar value to the current position but the problem is as the media is running the slider of the bar is not moving . i know i am missing something in the code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you actually update that information in LOOP. So it would be updated, for example, in timer. Every 1 second.

You can also check what values you get from those two calls(get_duration and get_position) using debugger.